# Finding IP address using Linux PID

Tags: linux

1. How to get IP address by using Pid in Linux. and what that pId doing.
   Is there any way?
2. Only allow the particular user only from that particular IP address, if that user use  apart from other IP address must to block. Only that user allow from that IP address.
   Is this Possible?

Answer (score 0):

It seem your question is bad written. If i understand what you are looking for:

**1/ About PID**

A PID is a process id. A process is linked to an user. An user can to be a local user or remote ( with ssh by example ) .

Into a shell if you put

```
$ ps u --pid 2525
```

Where 2525 is a pid, this command will tell to you which user is linked to this process

```
$ \w
```

That will display a list of user currently connected ( local and remotely ) with their corresponding external IP

Alternatively to \w you can use

```
$ who user3563068
```

This command is close to \w  and filter to given username

**2/ How to restrict remote access to your computer ?**

Using [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki) will block any external ip which fail to login. fail2ban is to me the way you should to take.

**Miscellaneous**

To see successful login:

```
$ last
```

To see unsuccessful login:

```
$ lastb
```

**Allowing access from only one IP:**

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.2 -j ACCEPT
```

Where 192.168.0.2 is your ip

Comment: question no 1. Unknown person's are access the server so that i want to see that person IP address and what he did in server. is there possible?

Comment: an unknown person's will try to brute force acess to you server. So it will try many password. This will be catch by fail2ban, and you will be able to list these ip

Comment: ok ok. Thank u so much. one more question is. one user access from particular IP address , apart from that IP address user can not able access. is there any possible to do this.

Comment: You are welcome . You can go to iptable to allow only one ip. see: http://serverfault.com/questions/261669/allowing-traffic-only-from-a-specified-ip-addresses-using-iptables . But if your ip change for any reason and you can't have a physical access that will be a problem.

Comment: Thank u for this info. But specific user can access from particular IP only, that user can not access the same from some other IP address. this is possible.?

Comment: I want to allow that user only from that IP, not from other IP address.

Comment: Please could you upvote my answer. I work to give an answer to your problem. And if that solve your problem mark it has resolved to help other user. Thanks

Comment: thank u. actually front end application ( php / .net / Java ) one user can access the website from specific IP address only, that same user can not access the website from other IP address. How to do this. is this possible?. please help me.

Comment: add it to iptable. iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.3 -j ACCEPT

Comment: thank u. i tried with this. but that user can access the web site from other IP address also. i want to block IP with user also. that user should not access from other IP.

Comment: Open another thread please. You current question is too far from original

Comment: maybe all my works do not fit with your last question but it seem to answer the original one. You could at least upvote it.